# CPython and PyPy Decimal operation performance

Tags: python, performance, math, floating-point, pypy

I would like to run some 100k+ simulations with some millions of data points, which are represented as decimals. I choose decimals over floats for floating point accuracy and ease of unit testing my logic (since `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1` does not equal 0.3 with floats...).

My hope was to speed up the simulations by using PyPy. But during my testing I encountered that PyPy does not handle `decimal.Decimal` or even `_pydecimal.Decimal` well at all - and gets dramatically slower than the CPython interpreter (which uses C for `decimal.Decimal` arithmetics). So I copy/pasted my whole codebase and replaced all `Decimal`s with `float`s and the performance increase was huge: x60-x70 times faster with PyPy than CPython - with the sacrifice of accuracy.

Are there any solutions to use Decimals precision in PyPy with the performance benefit? I "could" maintain two codebases: `float` for batch running the 100k simulations, `Decimal` for inspecting the interesting results later - but this bears the overhead of maintaining two codebases...

Here are some simple tests I ran on a `Raspberry Pi 4 (Ubuntu Server 20.10, 4 x 1.5GHZ ARM Cortex-A72, 8GB RAM)` for reproduction:

**test_decimal.py**

```
import time
from decimal import Decimal

start = time.time()
val = Decimal('1.0')
mul = Decimal('1.000001')
for i in range(10 * 1000 * 1000):
    val *= mul
end = time.time()
print(f"decimal.Decimal: {val:.8f} in {round(end-start,4)} sec")
```

**test_pydecimal.py**

```
import time
from _pydecimal import Decimal

start = time.time()
val = Decimal('1.0')
mul = Decimal('1.000001')
for i in range(10 * 1000 * 1000):
    val *= mul
end = time.time()
print(f"pydecimal.Decimal: {val:.8f} in {round(end-start,4)} sec")
```

**test_float.py**

```
import time
from decimal import Decimal

start = time.time()
val = float('1.0')
mul = float('1.000001')
for i in range(10 * 1000 * 1000):
    val *= mul
end = time.time()
print(f"float: {val:.8f} in {round(end-start,4)} sec")
```

**Results**

| Test | Python 3.8.6 (GCC 10.2.0) | Python 3.6.9 -PyPy 7.3.1 with GCC 10.2.0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test_decimal | 5.1131 sec | 55.0829 sec |
| test_pydecimal | 315.4012 sec | 40.1771 sec |
| test_float | 2.5607 sec | 0.1273 sec |

**Edit #1:**

- Updated the examples (use precomputed multiplicator, measure time outside of  `print`) and the results table: The overall comparison between PyPy and CPython performance on Decimals stays the same.
- The simulation mostly consists of the basic math operations (add, subtract, multiply, divide) over time-series data with changing values.

Comment: I haven't profiled it, but the `print()` may be skewing your results. I bet it takes more effort to convert a `decimal.Decimal` to a `str` than a `float`.  Try your timing experiments without the `print()`. It's important to understand that you're also timing the `print()`, which is not the correct way to time data manipulation unless you actually want to time `print()`. One of the reasons that timing `print()` is unreliable is due to buffering.

Comment: With `float('1.000001')` precomputed in a variable, `val` is the same but the execution is 4 times faster with Python and 63 times faster with PyPy... By the way, what level of precision do you want and what kind of operation do you do?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the input - I updated the examples with precumputed `val` and updated the results table and added information on the computation. A precision of `8` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **double-double precision** to achieve what you want significantly faster than arbitrary-precision arithmetic (ie. `Decimal`) and more accurate than double precision (ie. `float`). Double-double precision is generally slightly less accurate than quad-precision, but the latter is generally not natively supported on most platforms.

The [doubledouble](https://pypi.org/project/doubledouble/) Python package implement this and is compatible with PyPy. It does not support string parsing and formatting but you can implement this using the two slow following methods:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from doubledouble import DoubleDouble

def ddFromStr(s):
    hi = float(s)
    lo = float(Decimal(s) - Decimal(hi))
    return DoubleDouble(hi, lo)

def ddToStr(dd):
    return str(Decimal(dd.x) + Decimal(dd.y))
```

Here is how to use it:

```py
start = time.time()
val = ddFromStr('1.0')
mul = ddFromStr('1.000001')
for i in range(10 * 1000 * 1000):
    val *= mul
end = time.time()
print(f"doubledouble.DoubleDouble: {ddToStr(val)} in {round(end-start,4)} sec")
```

Here are the results on my machine:

```
CPython:
  float: 22026.35564471 in 0.6692 sec
  decimal.Decimal: 22026.35566283 in 1.4355 sec
  doubledouble.DoubleDouble: 22026.35566283 in 11.62 sec

PyPy:
  float: 22026.35564471 in 0.011 sec
  decimal.Decimal: 22026.35566283 in 16.3268 sec
  doubledouble.DoubleDouble: 22026.355662823 in 0.1184 sec
```

As you can see, **the `doubledouble` package on PyPy is significantly faster** than the `Decimal` package on CPython while the two provide equally accurate (truncated) results in this case.

Comment: This is awesome - thanks! I subclassed `DoubleDouble` with a `__init__` based on your `ddFromStr` - now i basically have a Drop-In-Replacement and don't need to change my codebase

Answer (score 0):

From this [issue in PyPy](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues/3024), the `_pydecimal` and `decimal` results should be equivalent in PyPy, since they are using the same code path. Multiplication/division in `_pydecimal` on PyPy with the JIT is about 8x slower than the C-based version in CPython, addition/subtraction is roughly equivalent.

Comment: This refers to an older PyPy and CPython implementation - and does not answer if there is a "way" to get decimal precision in PyPy with the speed benefit

Comment: The answer in that issue is still relevant today: there is currently no way to make PyPy faster in this comparison. You can sponsor a PyPy developer as a consultant to work on this problem, please reach out on the pypy-dev mailing list.