# data type 'float128' not understood

Tags: python, numpy

I was using LR for my spam and ham model, which shows overflow in exp. So I decided to make Y as a float128 value from float64.
It gives `TypeError: data type 'float128' not understood` as an error
I am using Jupyter notebook on a windows machine.
code for changing dtype is

```py
y = y.astype('float128')
print(y)
```

code for my LR model is

```py
import numpy as np
 
class LR:
     
    def sigmoid(self,z):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
     
    def add_intercept(self, X):
        intercept = np.ones((X.shape[0], 1))
        return np.concatenate((intercept, X), axis=1)
     
    def loss_func(self,X, y, weights):                 
        m =len(X)                
        yhat = sigmoid(np.dot(X, weights))        
        predict_1 = y * np.log(yhat)
        predict_0 = (1 - y) * np.log(1 - yhat)        
        return -sum(predict_1 + predict_0) / m
     
    def fit(self,X,y,epochs=25,learning_rate=0.05):
        loss = []
         
        X = self.add_intercept(X)
         
        weights = np.random.rand(X.shape[1])
        N = len(X)
 
        for _ in range(epochs):
            z = np.dot(X,weights)
            y_hat = sigmoid(z)
            weights -= learning_rate * (X.T @ (y_hat-y))/N
            loss.append(self.loss_func(X,y,weights))
        self.weights = weights
        self.loss = loss
        print(weights)
         
    def predict(self, X): 
        X = self.add_intercept(X)
        z = np.dot(X, self.weights)
        #Binary result
        return [1 if i > 0.5 else 0 for i in self.sigmoid(z)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float128` type is not yet supported by Numpy. Indeed, Numpy supports only native floating-point types and most platforms does not support 128-bit floating point precision. If using a higher precision than 64-bit floats is not an option for you, you can use double-double precision (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66646850/cpython-and-pypy-decimal-operation-performance/66654242#66654242) for more information). Alternatively, you can use the slow decimal Python package .