# Can numba use long doubles?

Tags: python, numba

In numpy float128 is typically a long double (not a 128 bit float). But I can’t tell if numba has support for this. The docs don’t seem to mention long doubles or the numpy type float128.

Answer (score 2):

No, **Numba does not support this type yet**. There is an [**open issue**](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8830) on this topic. The 80-bit extended precision is generally not well supported, even in Numpy. On mainstream x86-64 architecture, such numbers are computed by the x87 FPU unit which is pretty slow and rather obsolete nowadays.

If you want an extended precision, it may be better to use a **double-double** data-type like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66646850/cpython-and-pypy-decimal-operation-performance/66654242#66654242) (though you certainly need to port this into Numba yourself). Note that this data-type is not as precise as a 128-bit float but it can benefit from SIMD units (i.e. it is fast).

---

Another alternative is to just use double precision with **numerically stable algorithms**. The later solution is generally much better. Most people requesting for higher precision generally use numerically unstable algorithms where the error grows *exponentially* (possibly due to [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation)). Using a bigger precision does not really solve this issue : it just defer the problem at the expense of a much slower computation. Actually, double precision is sufficient for physicists to [simulate the universe](https://www.illustris-project.org/about/) with a pretty-high resolution. For example, double precision is enough for precisely locating atoms in a 1 meter domain. Using a 3-level hierarchical **clustering**, atoms can be precisely located in the Milky Way (with the size of 87_400 light-years). Note that clustering also tends to help to design faster programs (typically due to better algorithms, more cache-friendly accesses).

Comment: The open issue is about 128 bit floats not long doubles.

Comment: There is no long-double explicit direct support in Numpy so not in Numba either. Numpy typically implements the float128 as long-double internally which is 80-bit wide on x86-64 processors (they do not support 128-bit floats). Numba only supports the 32-bit and 64-bit floating point data-type. The discussion in the issue also applies for 80-bit floats (which are actually platform-specific).